# How to import a document with specific format to Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I am learning and follow tutorial at https://www.udemy.com/course/elasticsearch-complete-guide/ .

I am using `elasticsearch-7.12.0`, Kibana 7.12.0, Logstash 7.12.0 on Windows 10 x64, I have document

```json
{
    "index": {
        "_id": 1
    }
}
{
    "name": "Wine - Maipo Valle Cabernet",
    "price": 152,
    "in_stock": 38,
    "sold": 47,
    "tags": [
        "Alcohol",
        "Wine"
    ],
    "description": "Aliquam augue quam, sollicitudin vitae, consectetuer eget, rutrum at, lorem. Integer tincidunt ante vel ipsum. Praesent blandit lacinia erat. Vestibulum sed magna at nunc commodo placerat. Praesent blandit. Nam nulla. Integer pede justo, lacinia eget, tincidunt eget, tempus vel, pede. Morbi porttitor lorem id ligula.",
    "is_active": true,
    "created": "2004\/05\/13"
}
{
    "index": {
        "_id": 2
    }
}
{
    "name": "Tart Shells - Savory",
    "price": 99,
    "in_stock": 10,
    "sold": 430,
    "tags": [],
    "description": "Pellentesque at nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Cras in purus eu magna vulputate luctus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus vestibulum sagittis sapien. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam vel augue. Vestibulum rutrum rutrum neque. Aenean auctor gravida sem.",
    "is_active": true,
    "created": "2007\/10\/14"
}
```

Full file: https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/759d48d2ec96f70531d77d173cd9657e

I try

```
PUT _bulk
{
    "index": {
        "_id": 1
    }
}
{
    "name": "Wine - Maipo Valle Cabernet",
    "price": 152,
    "in_stock": 38,
    "sold": 47,
    "tags": [
        "Alcohol",
        "Wine"
    ],
    "description": "Aliquam augue quam, sollicitudin vitae, consectetuer eget, rutrum at, lorem. Integer tincidunt ante vel ipsum. Praesent blandit lacinia erat. Vestibulum sed magna at nunc commodo placerat. Praesent blandit. Nam nulla. Integer pede justo, lacinia eget, tincidunt eget, tempus vel, pede. Morbi porttitor lorem id ligula.",
    "is_active": true,
    "created": "2004\/05\/13"
}
{
    "index": {
        "_id": 2
    }
}
{
    "name": "Tart Shells - Savory",
    "price": 99,
    "in_stock": 10,
    "sold": 430,
    "tags": [],
    "description": "Pellentesque at nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Cras in purus eu magna vulputate luctus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus vestibulum sagittis sapien. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam vel augue. Vestibulum rutrum rutrum neque. Aenean auctor gravida sem.",
    "is_active": true,
    "created": "2007\/10\/14"
}
```

but not success.

My error

[image]

How to import the above document with specific format to Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
PUT /vy

POST /vy/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-07-10T16:52:43Z","lines":[{"product_id":6,"amount":71.32,"quantity":1},{"product_id":3,"amount":58.96,"quantity":3},{"product_id":1,"amount":29.8,"quantity":3}],"total_amount":160.08,"salesman":{"id":11,"name":"Matthus Mitkcov"},"sales_channel":"store","status":"processed"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-03-08T16:18:37Z","lines":[{"product_id":7,"amount":31.44,"quantity":2},{"product_id":4,"amount":74.82,"quantity":2}],"total_amount":106.26,"salesman":{"id":79,"name":"Ulberto Woodruff"},"sales_channel":"store","status":"completed"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-01-04T02:46:54Z","lines":[{"product_id":9,"amount":38.89,"quantity":1}],"total_amount":38.89,"salesman":{"id":68,"name":"Thea Chidgey"},"sales_channel":"store","status":"completed"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-04-14T11:44:29Z","lines":[{"product_id":4,"amount":26.18,"quantity":2},{"product_id":8,"amount":76.45,"quantity":1},{"product_id":1,"amount":65.59,"quantity":3}],"total_amount":168.22,"salesman":{"id":81,"name":"Melany Cerith"},"sales_channel":"store","status":"cancelled"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-02-18T17:11:21Z","lines":[{"product_id":2,"amount":56.06,"quantity":3},{"product_id":5,"amount":79.75,"quantity":3}],"total_amount":135.81,"salesman":{"id":23,"name":"Flynn Dome"},"sales_channel":"web","status":"completed"}
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-03-26T07:28:22Z","lines":[{"product_id":7,"amount":86.88,"quantity":1},{"product_id":5,"amount":27.34,"quantity":3},{"product_id":5,"amount":88.52,"quantity":2}],"total_amount":202.74,"salesman":{"id":16,"name":"Mirilla Penkman"},"sales_channel":"web","status":"completed"}
{"index":{"_id":7}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-05-06T18:37:33Z","lines":[{"product_id":3,"amount":25.27,"quantity":2}],"total_amount":25.27,"salesman":{"id":5,"name":"Modestia McCreadie"},"sales_channel":"app","status":"confirmed"}
{"index":{"_id":8}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-11-26T11:24:36Z","lines":[{"product_id":4,"amount":51.26,"quantity":1},{"product_id":8,"amount":72.41,"quantity":1}],"total_amount":123.67,"salesman":{"id":55,"name":"Grange Smiths"},"sales_channel":"phone","status":"cancelled"}
{"index":{"_id":9}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-12-26T08:29:47Z","lines":[{"product_id":2,"amount":98.87,"quantity":3}],"total_amount":98.87,"salesman":{"id":5,"name":"Carlyn Stegers"},"sales_channel":"web","status":"cancelled"}
{"index":{"_id":10}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-12-21T12:47:43Z","lines":[{"product_id":7,"amount":21.97,"quantity":3},{"product_id":10,"amount":19.26,"quantity":3}],"total_amount":41.23,"salesman":{"id":83,"name":"Kennie Gilks"},"sales_channel":"app","status":"cancelled"}
{"index":{"_id":11}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-04-02T04:42:31Z","lines":[{"product_id":6,"amount":86.89,"quantity":1},{"product_id":4,"amount":18.04,"quantity":3},{"product_id":10,"amount":18.61,"quantity":3}],"total_amount":123.54,"salesman":{"id":39,"name":"Ashely Rawnsley"},"sales_channel":"phone","status":"cancelled"}
{"index":{"_id":12}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-09-08T16:24:12Z","lines":[{"product_id":1,"amount":11.75,"quantity":1},{"product_id":5,"amount":77.33,"quantity":2},{"product_id":2,"amount":86.76,"quantity":1}],"total_amount":175.84,"salesman":{"id":40,"name":"Raynor Dennis"},"sales_channel":"web","status":"pending"}
{"index":{"_id":13}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-01-12T06:20:27Z","lines":[{"product_id":6,"amount":93.69,"quantity":2}],"total_amount":93.69,"salesman":{"id":62,"name":"Byran Gallihaulk"},"sales_channel":"app","status":"processed"}
{"index":{"_id":14}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-01-31T13:06:58Z","lines":[{"product_id":10,"amount":80.33,"quantity":2}],"total_amount":80.33,"salesman":{"id":43,"name":"Eveleen Ickovici"},"sales_channel":"store","status":"processed"}
{"index":{"_id":15}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-02-20T23:02:31Z","lines":[{"product_id":5,"amount":20.51,"quantity":1},{"product_id":10,"amount":93.35,"quantity":1}],"total_amount":113.86,"salesman":{"id":78,"name":"Erda Boyet"},"sales_channel":"store","status":"confirmed"}
{"index":{"_id":16}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-08-17T09:52:50Z","lines":[{"product_id":9,"amount":61.95,"quantity":1}],"total_amount":61.95,"salesman":{"id":91,"name":"Gherardo MattiCCI"},"sales_channel":"web","status":"confirmed"}
{"index":{"_id":17}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-06-05T18:59:23Z","lines":[{"product_id":8,"amount":32.46,"quantity":3},{"product_id":6,"amount":13.7,"quantity":2},{"product_id":8,"amount":28.74,"quantity":2}],"total_amount":74.9,"salesman":{"id":82,"name":"Shanon Eilhertsen"},"sales_channel":"phone","status":"confirmed"}
{"index":{"_id":18}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-07-26T12:10:15Z","lines":[{"product_id":3,"amount":23.16,"quantity":1},{"product_id":4,"amount":18.94,"quantity":1},{"product_id":10,"amount":38.65,"quantity":2}],"total_amount":80.75,"salesman":{"id":58,"name":"Thekla De Beauchemp"},"sales_channel":"phone","status":"processed"}
{"index":{"_id":19}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-05-08T19:54:44Z","lines":[{"product_id":9,"amount":29.8,"quantity":2},{"product_id":6,"amount":97.61,"quantity":3}],"total_amount":127.41,"salesman":{"id":96,"name":"Susannah Grigoryev"},"sales_channel":"phone","status":"cancelled"}
{"index":{"_id":20}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-06-19T21:34:51Z","lines":[{"product_id":2,"amount":23.3,"quantity":2},{"product_id":5,"amount":30.44,"quantity":2},{"product_id":6,"amount":22.15,"quantity":1}],"total_amount":75.89,"salesman":{"id":66,"name":"Janeta Crutchfield"},"sales_channel":"phone","status":"completed"}
{"index":{"_id":21}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-12-09T17:24:57Z","lines":[{"product_id":1,"amount":90.25,"quantity":1}],"total_amount":90.25,"salesman":{"id":20,"name":"Saxon Whitebread"},"sales_channel":"web","status":"cancelled"}
{"index":{"_id":22}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-09-18T12:26:52Z","lines":[{"product_id":7,"amount":48.03,"quantity":3},{"product_id":1,"amount":18.25,"quantity":1}],"total_amount":66.28,"salesman":{"id":96,"name":"Annissa Cleever"},"sales_channel":"web","status":"completed"}
{"index":{"_id":23}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-09-28T04:29:57Z","lines":[{"product_id":1,"amount":27.74,"quantity":3},{"product_id":8,"amount":82.88,"quantity":1}],"total_amount":110.62,"salesman":{"id":15,"name":"Catherina Tombleson"},"sales_channel":"phone","status":"pending"}
{"index":{"_id":24}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-08-05T23:08:23Z","lines":[{"product_id":5,"amount":90.7,"quantity":1}],"total_amount":90.7,"salesman":{"id":4,"name":"Saloma Raith"},"sales_channel":"app","status":"cancelled"}
{"index":{"_id":25}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-09-02T21:14:18Z","lines":[{"product_id":10,"amount":59.98,"quantity":1},{"product_id":4,"amount":34.72,"quantity":1}],"total_amount":94.7,"salesman":{"id":85,"name":"Raffaello Larrad"},"sales_channel":"web","status":"cancelled"}
{"index":{"_id":26}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-11-12T00:57:06Z","lines":[{"product_id":4,"amount":39.05,"quantity":3},{"product_id":8,"amount":39.29,"quantity":3}],"total_amount":78.34,"salesman":{"id":40,"name":"Maryanne O'Neill"},"sales_channel":"store","status":"confirmed"}
{"index":{"_id":27}}
{"purchased_at":"2016-12-30T07:37:52Z","lines":[{"product_id":7,"amount":12.41,"quantity":3},{"product_id":5,"amount":55.88,"quantity":3},{"product_id":6,"amount":33.89,"quantity":1}],"total_amount":102.18,"salesman":{"id":25,"name":"Myles Sedgemore"},"sales_channel":"web","status":"cancelled"}

{"purchased_at":"2016-10-03T15:57:59Z","lines":[{"product_id":9,"amount":12.15,"quantity":3},{"product_id":4,"amount":54.07,"quantity":1},{"product_id":10,"amount":83.01,"quantity":3}],"total_amount":149.23,"salesman":{"id":58,"name":"Leodora Mithon"},"sales_channel":"phone","status":"pending"}

GET /vy/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```